# How to prove these two integrals are equal?

Tags: integration

Is there a way to show that

$$\sigma\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \xi \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta + c)}{[1 + \exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta + c)]^2} \exp(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}) \exp(\frac{-\eta^2}{2}) d\xi d\eta = \\ \tau\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \eta \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta + c)}{[1 + \exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta + c)]^2} \exp(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}) \exp(\frac{-\eta^2}{2}) d\xi d\eta?$$

Numerically, with special cases, I can see it's true. I wonder if there's some sleek trick.

---

Also, if $c = 0$, I can show with even/odd functions that both integrals are 0.

Let $f(\xi, \eta) = \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)}{[1 + \exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)]^2}$. Then,

\begin{equation*}
f(-\xi, -\eta) = \frac{\exp\lbrace-(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace}{[1 + \exp\lbrace-(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace]^2}  \frac{\exp\lbrace2(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace}{\exp\lbrace2(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace} = \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)}{[\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta) (1 + \exp\lbrace-(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace)]^2} = f(\xi, \eta)
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
f(-\xi, \eta) = \frac{\exp\lbrace(-\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace}{[1 + \exp\lbrace(-\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)\rbrace]^2}  \frac{\exp\lbrace2(\sigma\xi - \tau\eta)\rbrace}{\exp\lbrace2(\sigma\xi - \tau\eta)\rbrace} = \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi - \tau\eta)}{[\exp(\sigma\xi - \tau\eta) (1 + \exp\lbrace-(\sigma\xi - \tau\eta)\rbrace)]^2} = f(\xi, -\eta)
\end{equation*}

Let $g(\xi, \eta) = \frac{\exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)}{[1 + \exp(\sigma\xi + \tau\eta)]^2} \exp(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}) \exp(\frac{-\eta^2}{2})$. Note that $g(-\xi, -\eta) = g(\xi, \eta)$. Also, $g(-\xi, \eta) = g(\xi, -\eta)$.

Now, let $s(\xi, \eta) = \xi g(\xi, \eta)$. Then,

$s(-\xi, -\eta) = -\xi g(-\xi, -\eta) = -\xi g(\xi, \eta) = -s(\xi, \eta)$, and

$s(-\xi, \eta) = -\xi g(-\xi, \eta) = -\xi g(\xi, -\eta) = -s(\xi, -\eta)$.

Finally,

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta &= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta 
+ \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{-\infty}^{0} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta}_{-\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta} \\
&+ \int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{0}^{\infty} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta + \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{0} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta}_{-\int_{-\infty}^{0} \int_{0}^{\infty} s(\xi, \eta)  d\xi d\eta}  \\
&= 0 \\
\end{align*}

So the left expression with $c = 0$ is 0. The right expression can be similarly shown.

Comment: Jesus... $\phantom{}$

Comment: @Crescendo I vote we move this comment to https://christianity.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Jesus" because it's obvious? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Just enforce the substitution

$$\xi \to \eta$$

And it's done.

Comment: Yes, both $\xi$ and $\eta$ have the same distribution of $N(0,1)$...I just took out the normalizing constant 1/2π1/2π. Sorry, what do you mean by enforce the substitution?

Comment: I meant: take an integral and substitute $\xi \to \eta$ or vice versa.

Comment: Isn't that only true when $\sigma = \tau$?